# Using requests library to see if a url is working, but getting unexpected result?

Tags: url, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have used the below function for a while and it always worked however, today when I put in this url it didn't. I have been scraping this site a lot recently (but respectfully) do you think my IP has been banned.

```
def server_online(url): 
    """Returns True if host responds to a ping request, else False"""
    try:
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1'}
        result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        if result.status_code == 200: 
            return True 
    except:   
        return False 
    return False
```

And then when I run the function with this link to a match below:

```
server_online('https://www.oddschecker.com/football/world-cup-european-qualifiers/cyprus-v-croatia/winner')
```

I get the result 'false' when it should (and usually is) 'true'

Comment: What is the status code being returned? Inspect the `result` object - it might give you 
a clue.

Comment: Your code gives a ```403``` status code.

Comment: Thanks guys, does anyone know a way around that?